# Apply change to a mediawiki skin

Tags: mediawiki, skin

I'm working on a `mediawiki` project. I want to know if I can create a new skin (from scratch) for `mediawiki` using frameworks like `Bootstrap`, `Angular material`,...

or I had a limit when it's come to changing `mediawiki` skin (how much in percentage?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaWiki has an [official Bootstrap extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Bootstrap), so you can use that for your skin.

Comment: How i can  work with `Angular material` [Angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/).@JuliePelletier